# See Maven Dependencies in Repository Scan (jQAssistant)

Tags: java, maven, jqassistant

I ran a jQAssistant scan on my Maven repository. Now I can see some information, but unfortunately, if I try

```
MATCH (a:Maven:Artifact) --> (b:Maven:Artifact) RETURN a
```

I see no results although there should be DEPENDS_ON connections between Artifacts. Is there some extra switch for the scan to also find these arcs?

Comment: Can you provide us a little bit more information? Could you please check first, if you use the database generated by jQAssistant? Please check first if there are any nodes in your database: `MATCH (a)--(b) RETURN a LIMIT 10;`

Comment: There are nodes. I have checked this.

Comment: Sure? Did you execute "jqassistant.cmd scan -u maven:repository::http://..." and "jqassistant.cmd server" from the same directory? If yes, what's the result of "match (n) return count(n)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're scanning a Maven repository there are no direct dependencies between artifacts, this is only the case if you're scanning a Maven reactor (i.e. using the Maven plugin).
In case of a repository you have the following structure:

- (:Repository)-[:CONTAINS_POM]->(:Pom)
- (:Pom)-[:DESCRIBES]->(:Artifact)
- (:Pom)-[:DECLARES_DEPENDENCY]->(:Artifact)

The following query returns all Poms, the artifacts which each of them describes and the dependencies that are declared:

```
MATCH
  (:Repository)-[:CONTAINS_POM]->(pom:Pom),
  (pom)-[DESCRIBES]->(artifact:Artifact),
  (pom)-[:DECLARES_DEPENDENCY]->(dependency:Artifact)
RETURN
  pom.fqn, collect(artifact.name), collect(dependency.fqn)
```

Comment: I admit that the documentation should be more clear on this and provide examples.

Comment: So I could use DESCRIBES and DECLARES_DEPENDENCY to define a dependency-arc from artifact to artifact (to use it e.g. for a transitive dependency tree)?

Comment: This should work, it would just mean to add the following part to the query above:

    MERGE
      (artifact)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(dependency)

Comment: I'm out of office now, I am going to try on Monday.